# (Java 1.16.2)Is there a way to detect a pulling bow and play sounds via resources packs or commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-resource-packs

I want to play sounds when bows are pulled, which they usually won't do that. Although I want to set it in sounds.json in my resources pack, it don't have the events of pulling bow.

So I am looking for commands that detect bow pulling, or sounds.json events which can do that.

I feel really nervous about this.

Answer (score 1):

The only sound in vanilla minecraft that occurs when pulling a form of bow is when loading crossbows, not standard bows.

Those sounds are as follows:

```
item/crossbow/loading_start
item/crossbow/loading_middle1
item/crossbow/loading_middle2
item/crossbow/loading_middle3
item/crossbow/loading_middle4
item/crossbow/loading_end
```

and you can find the wiki page on them [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Crossbow#Sounds) and [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json/Java_Edition_values).

If you want to make standard bows do this, you'll probably need to mod the game.